# Error on crossing two numpy (vector defined function) arrays in SAGE

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sage

Let `u=u(x),v=v(x)` be two vector functions defined in SAGE as follows:

```
import numpy as np
x = var('x')
f,g = function('f',x), function('g',x)
f(x), g(x) = 2*x, sin(x)
u,v = np.array([f,g]),np.array([g,f])
c = np.cross(u,v)
```

When trying to cross `u,v` I get the following error (it seems strange because `np.dot(u,v)` works perfectly)

Error:

```
sage: np.cross(u,v,axisa=0,axisb=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4f0f99d7c55e> in <module>()
----> 1 np.cross(u,v,axisa=Integer(0),axisb=Integer(0))

/usr/lib/sagemath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in cross(a, b, axisa, axisb, axisc, axis)
   1329         if (b.shape[0] == 2):
   1330             cp = a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]
-> 1331             if cp.ndim == 0:
   1332                 return cp
   1333             else:

/usr/lib/sagemath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/structure/element.so in sage.structure.element.Element.__getattr__ (sage/structure/element.c:3846)()

AttributeError: 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

UPDATE (solution): Use SAGE's `u.cross_product(v)` on 3D vectors

Comment: Just to clarify as well, your line with `f,g=...` probably won't do anything because the next line will overwrite that, and given that you have *symbolic* elements `f,g` it is unlikely that Numpy would really be able to do much with them anyway.  If you are looking for "pure Python" solutions, Sympy should have much of what you are looking for (and is built-in standard in Sage).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 1st dim of `a` and `b` is 2, it is calculating

```
cp = a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]
```

For an ordinary numpy array, this works fine:

```
np.cross([1,2],[2,1])  # -3
```

because

```
np.array([1,2])[0].ndim  # 0
```

I don't have Sage, but your error message says that the elements of the arrays are `sage.symbolic.expression.Expression` objects.

I can reproduce your error with other arrays with `dtype=object`:

```
In [79]: f=np.array((1,2),dtype='O')  # array([1, 2], dtype=object)
In [80]: g=np.array((2,1),dtype='O')

In [83]: np.cross(f,g)
...
-> 1501             if cp.ndim == 0:
   1502                 return cp
   1503             else:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ndim'

In [84]: np.dot(f,g)
Out[84]: 4

In [86]: f[0]
Out[86]: 1

In [87]: f[0].ndim
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-45759919b9dd> in <module>()
----> 1 f[0].ndim

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Clearly, when `np.cross` was written they did not expect it to be used with object arrays.  Ones that would produce errors with this test: `if cp.ndim == 0:`

Comment: ΟΚ, got it! But why are the other operations (on sage function objects) possible? For example, as aforementioned, `np.dot(u,v)` works perfectly

Comment: Both your Sage objects and my test ones return a number when indexed (`a[0]`), it just isn't wrapped in a `numpy` type (i.e. Python `int` instead of `np.int8`).  For a lot of purposes they behave the same.  It just happens that `np.cross` chose `ndim==0` to distinguish between scalar and array results.